# Do I need recompile all JSP files if upgrading tomcat 5.5 to tomcat 7.0

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web

I am upgrading tomcat 5.5 to tomcat 7.0.
Do you think it's necessary to  recompile all JSP files to make sure everything works?

Comment: no ... just put war file tomcat manage it

Comment: for tomcat...I dont think so... You dont have to recompile unless you are migrating to a newer java version and ur using a feature that newer version of java provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use JSP files then there will be nothing to do. Tomcat compiles them on first access and any JSP that works with 5.5.x will work with 7.0.x.

If you have pre-compiled JSPs then you will need to recompile them to move from 5.5.x to 7.0.x. Pre-compiled JSPs use Tomcat's internal API and that is not guaranteed to be fixed between point releases, let alone between major versions. The most notable change that comes to mind is that the set of dependencies for compiled JSPs was tracked as a List in 5.5.x but is tracked as a Map in 7.0.x.

For similar reasons, when upgrading Tomcat you should clear out the work directory to ensure that JSPs are recompiled.